# Disable autoescaping in jinja2 on Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

By default, jinja2 autoescapes everything, and I want to stop this. I'm using the following code in a BaseHandler class:

```
@webapp2.cached_property
def jinja2(self):
    # Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry.
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)
```

According to the [docs](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html), get_jinja2() has a callable "factory" argument which defaults to Jinja2(). I presume I need change this to Jinja2(config={'autoescape':False}), but how do you specify arguments for the factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `get_jinja2` with `factory` set to a callable constructing the jinja instance with your customer parameters:

```
@webapp2.cached_property
def jinja2(self):
    # Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry, with no autoescaping.
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(lambda app: jinja2.Jinja2(app=app,config={'environment_args':{'autoescape':False}}))
```

Comment: Awesome - should have thought of lambda. I've made a minor correction to the parameters (app is required, and config has an extra environment_args layer) so it actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

may be you don't need to escape the whole template, in that case you could try the tag:

```
    `{{autoescape false}}`
```

for more details try the 
[docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping) :

Comment: Thanks - that is worth pointing out. However, you get better performance with autoescaping off, so if you are confident you don't need autoescaping most of the time it's better to escape just the dangerous fields with the e filter.